# Iterate through map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to put markers to the specific cities that I chose but I need to do it in a for loop, manually going through the process is time-consuming and looks quite ugly on the code. Any tips to use a for loop correctly? What am I doing wrong here?

```
var izmir = {lat: 38.4237, lng: 27.1428};
  var amsterdam = {lat: 52.3680, lng: 4.9036};
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4,
      center: izmir});
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4,
        center: amsterdam});
        var i;
        for(i=0;i.length;i++)
        {
           nokta = new google.maps.Marker({position: izmir,amsterdam, map: map});
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I guess I've partly achieved what I wanted, only problem is that the marker is only used by the last entry, in this case it's Prague. If I change it to another city (e.g. Amsterdam), map is centered on Amsterdam and the marker is only used by Amsterdam. How can I use the marker on all?

```
 var sehirler = {
    'izmir': {lat: 38.4237, lng: 27.1428},
    'amsterdam': {lat: 52.3680, lng: 4.9036},
    'prague': {lat: 50.0755, lng: 14.4378}};
function initMap() {

  for (var sehir in sehirler)
  {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    {zoom: 4, center: sehirler[sehir]});
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: sehirler[sehir], map: map});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED based on discussion below

is this what you're looking for?

```
// initialize object containing all cities
var sehirler = {
    izmir: { lat: 38.4237, lng: 27.1428 },
    amsterdam: { lat: 52.368, lng: 4.9036 },
    prague: { lat: 50.0755, lng: 14.4378 }
};

function initMap() {
    // initialize main map
    var center = sehirler.CITY // <-- edit CITY to be the correct city
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4, center: center });

    // iterate throughout cities to put all markers on same map
    for (var sehir in sehirler) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: sehirler[sehir], map: map });
    }
}
```

Comment: function initMap() {
      for(var sehir in sehirler)
      {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
          {zoom: 4, center: sehirler[sehir]});
          var nokta = new google.maps.Marker({position: sehirler, map: map});
      }
    }

What am I missing here?

Comment: this is valid code. what do you expect it to do? what is it doing?

Comment: Yes, multiple markers on a single map. Can be centered on any city that I will create

Comment: Yes! This is what I'm looking for. Thanks.